# How to join output of models in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following code:

```
$orders = OrderProduct::where(function ($query) use ($request) {

})->with('order_products')->orderBy('status', 'desc')->paginate(50)->toArray();
```

And `order_products` function is:

```
 public function order_products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Order", "order_id", "order_id");
    }
```

It gives me output result:

```
{
        "user_id": "1",
        "created_at": "2016-12-18 14:06:11",
        "status": "2",
        "note": "34535345",
        "order_id": "2",
        "address": "Kiev",
        "courier_id": null,
        "payment_type": "0",
        "order_products": [
          {
            "id": 73,
            "product_id": "1265",
            "amount": "1"
          },
          {
            "id": 74,
            "product_id": "1266",
            "amount": "1"
          }
        ]
```

I need to join `order_products` with `products_details`, that to give title of product for each order like as:

```
"order_products": [
              {
                "id": 73,
                "product_id": "1265",
                "amount": "1",
                "title": "Product name"
              },
              {
                "id": 74,
                "product_id": "1266",
                "amount": "1",
                "title": "Product name"
              }
            ]
```

Instead this I get a new model output in response:

```
"products_details": [
  {}, {}
]
```

How can I join two `with` models?

Comment: this is very well structured output

Comment: hi there can you include the table structure of this 2 models using

Comment: Show your relation and DB schema in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without joining, just using your first code:

in `order_products`, override the `toArray()` method.

```
function toArray() {
  return [
    id         => $this->id,
    product_id => $this->product_id,
    amount     => $this->amount,
    title      => $this->details->name
  ];
}
```

wich `$this->details->name` is the relation between `order_products` and `products_details`